# Floating divs stack horizontally to fill parent div and responsive resize

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, responsive-design

I've created this metro tile slider, but I'm having issues making it responsive.

Here is what I've created so far:
http://bit.ly/189HN4Y

The first issue is, the tiles don't line up horizontally unless I surround it with a div with a width of 1000px.

The second issue is, the tiles are not responsive. This could be because I had to set a pixel width on the surrounding div, but I think there may be other issues causing this. I'd like the tiles to stay stacked horizontally and just shrink when I view in a mobile device.

I created these tiles in Wordpress with the Tile Builder plugin. If you view their example in a mobile device, you will see that it shrinks, and this is the desired behavior I want:
http://bit.ly/189HRSa

I've been at this for a while trying to tweak the surrounding div, the widget area I created, and even the theme, but nothing has worked. Hoping another pair of eyes can help me figure this out...

Answer (score 0):

To make it responsive, you are going to need to define the width of each element as percentage follow my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/KAeak/1/

I used just a single wrapper

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="element-1">Test</div>
    <div id="element-2">Test</div>
    <div id="element-3">Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using a percentage on the width, but not on the height, skews my tiles. I need the width and the height to shrink in mobile browsers. Setting a percentage for width AND height makes the tile disappear.

Comment: Just set a min-height and a max-height, you can use max-width and min-width too :)

Answer (score 0):

1. To fix the problem with tiles center alignment, remove the `display: table-cell;` or just add `width: 1000px` in the class `.art-layout-cell` on your `style.css` file at line 1480;
2. To make it responsive, use percentage width in the tiles OR/AND `@media screen`'s [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/r788j/).

This example you say, they use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 />` to make it shrinks, but ALL site shrinks too. The best way to do it responsive are @media screen's

Comment: I wasn't really asking about center alignment. I need the width and the height of the tiles to shrink when the browser shrinks.

Comment: How not? Was your first issue!
@media queries don't help you? or perhaps percentage width?